# Can you apply a limit on promQL query?

Tags: limit, prometheus, promql, victoriametrics

For example:

```
Avg by (server) (HttpStatusCodes{category = 'Api.ResponseStatus'}) limit 10
```

Is this valid in promQl? I can not find anything about it in the documentation. Thanks

Comment: [bottomk or topk](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) may help

Answer (score 5):

The provided query is valid [MetricsQL](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html) query for VictoriaMetrics, but unfortunately it doesn't work in the original PromQL.

Prometheus provides [topk
and bottomk operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators), which can be used for limiting the number of returned time series. Unfortunately, these operators limit the number of returned time series on a per-point basis (considering points on the graph). This means that the total number of returned time series may exceed the requested limit. MetricsQL solve this issue with a family of `topk_*` and `bottomk_*` functions. See [MetricsQL docs](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html) for details.